# Has anyone wielded both Infinity Gauntlets at the same time?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, infinity-stones

In the mid-credits scene of *Age of Ultron*, we see

> a left-handed Infinity Gauntlet.

Previously in Odin’s chamber, in *Thor*, we see a right-handed Infinity Gauntlet.

My question is,

> Has anybody wielded both of them at the same time?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the vault gauntlet ? I don't think it's the Infinity Gauntlet that is stored in Asgard's Vault.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, no one has been seen wielding either Infinity Gauntlet.

- The right hand Infinity Gauntlet in Odin's trophy hall has gems on it but it is unlikely those gems are real because we know where four of the gems are at the moment. We also know the Tesseract is NOT on the Infinity Gauntlet in the trophy chamber because it was used to repair the broken Bifrost.

[image]

> We have seen the left Infinity Gauntlet in Thanos' secret lair and when he puts it on, it has NO gems on it either. This means we are left to assume either the Gauntlets have some properties of their own without the Infinity gems on them or one of these gauntlets is a mockup or model. Or there could be some new Marvel Cinematic Universe story explaining why there are TWO Infinity Gauntlets even though the comics only had one such gauntlet at a time.

#### HOWEVER: On Earth-1610 (Ultimate Marvel Earth)

There were TWO infinity gauntlets (but still only one set of gems) as seen below:

[image]

> - In the Ultimate Marvel universe, a version of the Infinity Gauntlet is seen in Project Pegasus. The Mind Gem (stolen by Hydra) is used by Modi (Thor's son) to control both Director Flumm and Cassie Lang, but are stopped by the Ultimates.
> - The Gem of Power is later revealed to be in the possession of former S.H.I.E.L.D. agent Sayuri Kyota, while a second Infinity Gauntlet is recovered from an A.I.M. base by Thor and Susan Storm. Kang the Conqueror later allies himself with the Hulk, Reed Richards and Quicksilver as part of a plan to steal the two Gauntlets, which results in the destruction of the Triskelion. Quicksilver recovers two additional gems allowing the villains to teleport away.
> - Richards is later able to recover another of the gems, which is found lodged in Tony Stark's brain. He informs Stark that the Infinity Gems are needed to save the world from a coming cataclysm that will destroy the entire universe. After brainwashing Johnny Storm and forcing him to travel to the Earth's core, the Dark Ultimates are able to recover the final gem, but are defeated by the Ultimates. The gems then shatter, rendering the Gauntlets useless. **([REF: Wikipedia - Infinity Gems - Ultimate Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems#Ultimate_Marvel))**

**Since the Marvel Cinematic Universe appears to use information from both the Earth-616 and the Earth-1610 universes, it is possible the second gauntlet exists because of those storylines.**

Comment: Two Infinity Gauntlets would be so overpowered it's insane. Hey, I know - let's take the two Infinity Gauntlets from the MCU and put a Green Lantern ring on each finger. Then let's give that power to Thanos or Darkseid... or Batman.

Comment: Doesn't the Ultimate universe have two gauntlets? I believe they were part of the Dark Ultimates storyline. Since the movies seem closer to that universe that might explain the existence of two.

Comment: @Omegacron Isn't the only use of the Gauntlet to hold the Gems? That is, having two doesn't really benefit you.

Comment: @KSmarts originally in the 616 yea - it only served to hold the gems. Other realities are different, though, and realistically they can do whatever they want in the MCU.

Comment: @KSmarts except what well-dressed megalomaniac would want to be seen with just one gauntlet...  how gauche!